# Passing array within functions - form validation & display error

Tags: arrays, function, return, php-5.5

I have 3 functions (cut down version of what I am trying to do). It seems when the function returns the array, it only returns the last value (which is null in my case) and loses the values appended before:

```
    function addError($err){
      $error = array();
      if ($err != NULL){
          $error[] = $err;
     }
       return $error; 
     }

    // temp function to populate addError
    function populateError(){
       for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++){
       addError($i);
      } 
    }

    // temp function to display Errors
    function display(){
       $v = addError(NULL); 
       print_r($v); 
    }
   //to test the functions
    populateError(); 
    display();
```

When I call display function, it gives an empty array. I tried to print it in the function addError, just before return statement and it has the values, but when called from another function (display) only empty array is printed as I am passing NULL to the function when calling.

Not quite sure how I can achieve this, I am hoping the function will return an array with all the values appended in the cycle (one form submit). I would greatly appreciate any help/pointer. Much thanks in advance!

Comment: The logic you are using is wrong! See you populateError() function calls the add error function 20 times and each time a new $error array is created! It does not retain the previous values! Also, the value returned by this function is catched by no variable in populateError(). Thats why its not working!!

Comment: Thank you @freerunner, I think I understand what you mean. But how should I store the value (retain) in an array (for example, addError to store all the values sent by populateError()) and then access them through another function so I can display the error? Sorry, I am sure its something very silly, but I seem to have a mental block and can't seem to see it through.

Comment: You have to use a global variable for that which is not a good practice. if you understand OOP then the best way to do would be using class attributes! It is good to separate codes into different sections both for re-usability and control, but I think you are using unnecessary functions here! Just a suggestion.The codes can be better arranged. Can you tell me what are you up to? I might be able to help you better then!!

Comment: Thank you @freerunner! I am new to php & trying to learn. I find the procedural way easier than OOP (dumb, I know!). Simply put, I want to have a function which is called every time there's an error, for e.g, form validation (invalid email, phone etc). And the validation function calls the addError() & passes the invalid field name while returning false. The user gets redirected to form page, with querystring blah.php?e=y (for e.g) and then display error gets active highlighting all the invalid fields with some 'sense-making' msg. Sorry to lay it all here *gulp* Any pointer would be great!

Answer (score 0):

ok, so I figured out the problem. Not sure if it will help anyone, but I was redirecting the user on validation error (via header tag) and as a result the variable values were being lost. Instead of that I included the functions page after form was posted and the page was posted to self, as a result I could display the errors, highlight fields etc. I am still not convinced with this way and the code quality, but as a step one it seems to be working, now to improving it. Hopefully, someone else can also benefit from this, Thank you!